# Rabbitmq server start failed with file locked

Tags: java, server, rabbitmq

Rabbitmq 3.6.5 start failed with this. How to fix it?

```
BOOT FAILED
   ===========

   Error description:    "Found lock file at ~s.\n            Either previous upgrade is in progress or has failed.\n            Database
   backup path: ~s"

   Log files (may contain more information):   
   /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@vm-10-111-29-211.log   
   /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@vm-10-111-29-211-sasl.log

   Stack trace:    [{rabbit_upgrade,ensure_backup_taken,
       ["/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@vm-10-111-29-211/schema_upgrade_lock", "/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@vm-10-111-29-211-upgrade-backup"],
       [{file,"src/rabbit_upgrade.erl"},{line,101}]},
       {rabbit_upgrade,maybe_upgrade_mnesia,0,
                       [{file,"src/rabbit_upgrade.erl"},{line,144}]},
       {rabbit,'-boot/0-fun-0-',0,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,271}]},
       {rabbit,start_it,1,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,403}]},
       {init,start_it,1,[]},
       {init,start_em,1,[]}]

   {"init terminating in do_boot","Found lock file at ~s.\n           
   Either previous upgrade is in progress or has failed.\n           
   Database backup path: ~s"}

   Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump init terminating in do_boot
   (Found lock file at ~s.
               Either previous upgrade is in progress or has failed.
               Database backup path: ~s)
```

Comment: Not a question for SO.  Please refer to: [Ask]. This belongs on serverfault.com. You also didn't even bother to complete the 2-minute site tour before asking.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you have had a problem during the database upgrade, it would be interesting see what happened checking the logs

BTW To solve quickly the problem is enough to remove your `mnesia` directory.

The directory is usually located in `/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia` , check [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/relocate.html) for detail.

**NOTE**

**By removing the `mnesia` directory you will lose all your messages**

Comment: Thank you, but after delete the directory, it reports another error below
Error description: {aborted,undef}
Stack trace:
   [{mnesia,abort,1,[{file,"mnesia.erl"},{line,318}]},
    {rabbit_node_monitor,legacy_cluster_nodes,1,
                         [{file,"src/rabbit_node_monitor.erl"},{line,789}]},
    {rabbit_node_monitor,prepare_cluster_status_files,0,
                         [{file,"src/rabbit_node_monitor.erl"},{line,121}]},
    {rabbit,'-boot/0-fun-0-',0,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,270}]}...

Comment: Add 'sudo' before works, I don't know why, I'm login with root already. Thank u again.