# RabbitMQ server is falling

Tags: rabbitmq, windows-server-2008-r2

I don't know why the RabbitMQ service is falling on Windows Server 2008 R2. It was working before, but now it can no longer stabilize the service. I can't even access the Broker at http://localhost:15672/#/

Any magic trick?

Comment: This log message seems to say nothing to me:


`=INFO REPORT==== 25-Jul-2018::10:28:51 ===
Error description:
   "Found lock file at ~s.\n            Either previous upgrade is in progress or has failed.\n            Database backup path: ~s"

Log files (may contain more information):
   C:/Users/{user}/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/log/RABBIT~1.LOG
   C:/Users/{user}/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/log/RABBIT~2.LOG`

Comment: `Stack trace:
   [{rabbit_upgrade,ensure_backup_taken,
                    ["c:/Users/{user}/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/db/RABBIT~1/schema_upgrade_lock",
                     `

Comment: `"c:/Users/{user}/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/db/RABBIT~1-upgrade-backup"],
                    [{file,"src/rabbit_upgrade.erl"},{line,104}]},
    {rabbit_upgrade,maybe_upgrade_mnesia,0,
                    [{file,"src/rabbit_upgrade.erl"},{line,147}]},
    {rabbit,'-boot/0-fun-0-',0,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,275}]},
    {rabbit,start_it,1,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,303}]},
    {init,start_it,1,[{file,"init.erl"},{line,1055}]},
    {init,start_em,1,[{file,"init.erl"},{line,1035}]}]`

Comment: Still not working as a Windows Service, but doing this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41297427/6949163 it works as an Application. Ref.: https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows-manual.html#running-windows